# button not clickable when gridview added to framelayout

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, android-framelayout

I have a framelayout with a a textview at the center and button (in included bar.xml) placed at the bottom. The button works perfectly at run time. However, I later add to it a gridview and make the textview invisible. After this, however, the button seizes to recieve and touch or click events.

Anyone know how to achieve this? Or alternative ways to create the same layout.

When I remove the button from the framelayout, it works perfectly even when the gridview shows up. Here's some of my code.

result.xml

```
<!-- Frame 1 -->
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/result_fragment_container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/result_error"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="No results found."
        android:textColor="@color/theme_support_color"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />      

  <include  
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:id ="@+id/result_bar"
       layout="@layout/bar" />


</FrameLayout>
```

And bar.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:id="@+id/sl_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/search_location"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/address_height"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end" 
    />


    <!-- Problematic Button -->
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button_change_location"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/address_change_button_height"
        android:text="Change"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Handling Code From MainActivity:

```
 @Override
public void onVolleyDone(JSONObject response) {

    //second frame layout
    FragmentManager fragmentManager  = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    //send the shop id
    ArrayList<ListItem> listItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

    System.out.println("Volley done counted "+counter);
    counter++;
    //if it returned any items
    if(!response.isNull("item_0")){

        //check if the error view is visible
        if(errorView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            errorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

         for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
             try {

                JSONObject jObject = response.getJSONObject("item_"+i);

                String iName = jObject.getString("item_name");
                String iImage = jObject.getString("primary_image");
                int iId =  Integer.valueOf(jObject.getString("id"));

             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }



         itemsFragment.setListItems(listItems);
         fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.result_fragment_container, itemsFragment); 
         fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }else{
        errorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }


}
```

ItemsListFragment referenced above:

```
public class ItemsListFragment extends Fragment implements   OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener{


//variables
private ItemsListAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<ListItem> listItems;
private GridView gridView;
private ArrayList<ListItem> tempShopItems;
private OnListItemClickListener callBack;
public static final int GRID_NUM_COLUMNS = 2;
private static final String TAG = ItemsListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int LONG_CLICK = 2;
public static final int SHORT_CLICK = 3;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_list_fragment, container,false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    //initialize other variables
    initVariables();


    //get items to display
        updateItems();

}

 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            callBack = (OnListItemClickListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListItemClickListener");
        }
    }



private void initVariables(){

    //shop items
    listItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

    //grid view
    gridView = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    gridView.setNumColumns(GRID_NUM_COLUMNS);

    //adapter
    adapter = new ItemsListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),listItems);


    //set onitemclick listener
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    //set adapter
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {


    if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position) instanceof Item){
         //start another activity

    }else
        callBack.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id,SHORT_CLICK);
}





public void setListItems(ArrayList<ListItem> items){
    tempShopItems = items;
    System.out.println("Temp items after= "+tempShopItems.toString());

}



public void updateItems(){
    listItems.addAll(0, tempShopItems);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void removeFromList(int index){
    listItems.remove(index);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    callBack.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id, LONG_CLICK);
    return true;
}

public interface OnListItemClickListener{
    public void onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id, int type);
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code you can show us? Your description is pretty vague.

Comment: Sample code just added.

Comment: please include the java code for handling this layout